edges bridging tool in Blender
I try to create a face between two or more edges, there are different situations, is there a filling method in Blender that can achieve this effect. The fill parts are between red lines.
One situation: two edges, they are close in size

another situation: two edges, they are not close in size

another situation: three edges


For the 2 first situations you have right click > LoopTools > Bridge, or Ctrl E >Bridge Edge Loops, the third situation is more complicated...

thank you have much, I wonder if there have addons to solve the problem
